# how to jump to stack trace errors from packages in compilation mode

Tags: emacs, dart

I am trying to get *Compilation mode* to correctly identify source files with errors in Dart. Here is a sample stack trace.

```
Illegal argument(s): Id has invalid characters sample.xmi
#0      Id.Id (package:ebisu/src/ebisu_id/id.dart:23:7)
#1      id (package:ebisu/src/ebisu_dart_meta/meta.dart:1104:22)
#2      library (package:ebisu/src/ebisu_dart_meta/meta.dart:1108:46)
#3      Converter.convert (file:///home/user/open_source/codegen/dart/xmi/lib/xmi_to_dart.dart:44:30)
#4      main (file:///home/user/open_source/codegen/dart/xmi/lib/xmi_to_dart.dart:164:20)
```

First, I'm not sure the best dart-mode to use. I have found these two:

- https://github.com/nex3/dart-mode/blob/master/dart-mode.el
- http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dart/tools/utils/elisp/dart-mode.el

Not sure which is recommended? I am trying to use the first but I don't see anything related to compilation error support. The latter has something for it, but it is not matching (probably out of date as the compiler messages/stack traces have evolved). Here, in my attempt, I have added these lines to the first dart mode file:

```
(require 'compile)
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist 'dart)
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist 
             '(dart "(file://\\([^:]*\\):\\([0-9]*\\):\\([0-9]*\\))" 1 2 3))
```

So, this does match the lines listed as '...(file:///...)' and correctly jumps to the error. It (or some other expression) falsely identifies lines like the #0 stack frame in the example '...(package:ebisu/src/...)' and leaves an error type message with "Find this error in ..." in the minibuffer requesting me to input the file name to jump to. I want to fix this. So, two questions really, I'm not sure how it got the match for package, maybe some other matching algorithm? And second, is there a way to match the '#0' stack frame such that it just looks for the file in the current directory (CWD) and treats the text

```
(package:ebisu/src/ebisu_id/id.dart:23:7)
```

as the equivalent of

```
(file://CWD/packages/ebisu/src/ebisu_id/id.dart:23:7)
```

where CWD is text replaced with current working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply the patch in [Emacs bug 11777](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11777) to compile.el, you should be able to do something like:

```
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist 'dart-package)
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist 
             '(dart-package "(package:\\([^:]*\\):\\([0-9]*\\):\\([0-9]*\\))"
                            (1 "packages/%s") 2 3))
```

The docstring for `compilation-error-regexp-alist` mentions this format string trick, but it doesn't seem to work properly without the patch.